# Loopback always returns results

Tags: javascript, loopback

So i have the following table:

**external_user_has_survey_question_answer**

[image]

This table has a `belongsTo` relation to the table:

**external_user**

[image]

Now i am trying to query data where `member_id` is equal to `3`

```
  loopbackModels.findModel("external_user_has_survey_question_answer").find({
        include:
            {
                relation: 'external_user',
                scope: {
                    where: {member_id: member_id}
                }
            },
        where:{member_id: member_id}
    }, function (err,result) {
        cb(err,result);
    });
```

Problem is that no matter what I do (even if the `member_id` does not exist in my database) I get all results.

So my question is what have i done wrong?

Also here is my relation:

```
"relations": {
    "external_user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "external_user",
      "foreignKey": "external_user_id"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be modified to

```
 loopbackModels.findModel("external_user_has_survey_question_answer").find({
    include:
        {
            relation: 'external_user',
            scope: {
                where: {member_id: member_id}
            }
        }
}, function (err,result) {
    cb(err,result);
});
```

And also all the results in `external_user_has_survey_question_answer` will be shown but the relation(key) `external_user` will be empty